# How to do this using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table (`DatosMex`) in `R` and would like to recode a column within it named `industry`. The distinct categories for this variable are:

```
  Agricultura,Ganaderia,Pesca,Caza Forestal                      
  Asociaciones                                                       
  Comercio                                                       
  Construccion                                                   
  Energia,Petroleo,Gas,Mineria                                   
  Gobierno                                                       
  Industria                                                      
  N/A                                                            
  NULL                                                           
  Servicios
```

I want to create a new variable, say `gr_industry`, that groups some categories. For instance, my new variable must group the categories `Agricultura,Ganaderia,Pesca,Caza Forestal`, `Asociaciones`,`Energia,Petroleo,Gas,Mineria` and `Gobienro` and assign them the code 1.

How would you do this using the `data.table` package syntax?

My approach was this:

```
 #Create an id for each industry
 DatosMex[,cod_industria:=as.numeric(DatosMex$industry)] 
 #Create a new data table
 ind =data.table(cod_industria=c(1:10),gr_industry=c(1,1,2,3,1,1,4,6,6,5))
 setkey(DatosMex,cod_industria)
 setkey(ind,cod_industria)
 DatosMex[ind]
```

So, as you can see, I had to create a new data table `ind` and then do the inner join. My question is: is there another way of doing this using the `data.table` way? I don't want to create a table each time I need to do something similar. Also, I'd like to avoid using if statements.

Comment: Are `NULL` and `NA` meaningful factor levels or do they reflect missing values?

Comment: Also, you don't need to refer to the data.table within the `j` component of `[`, eg `DatosMex[,cod_industria:=as.numeric(industry)]` will work.

Comment: @mnel I want to treat them (``NULL`` and ``NA``) as missing values. On the other hand, you are right, I don't need to refer to the data table within the ``j`` component. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing one does not need to set a key or create a new data.table. The `[` function is generally very fast, especially in datatable-objects:

```
 DatosMex[, gr_industry := c(1,1,2,3,1,1,4,6,6,5)[cod_industria] ]
```

If that grouping translation vector is large then you can refer to it by name, even if it is outside the data.table.

```
 dta <- data.table(a=sample(1:10, 20, repl=TRUE))
 g6<- c(1,1,2,3,1,1,4,6,6,5)
 dta[ , ind := g6[a] ]
 #-------------------
     a ind
 1:  8   6
 2:  4   3
 3: 10   5
 4:  8   6
 snipped output
```

Comment: could you explain me what is this part (``c(1,1,2,3,1,1,4,6,6,5)[cod_industria]``) doing? It is working fine, but I'd like to understand your solution. I'm not that expert using ``data.table`` package, but I'm trying to get used to it. Thanks!

Comment: Basically is says: "Use each value of `cod_industria` to pick the group number from that vector." It's just using ordinary R numeric indexing to map each of your detail data to a more compact grouping.

Answer (score 2):

From an code organization point of view, you need to define the recoding at some point, either

- in a `data.table` or
- a switch function.

Here is a switch function example

```
  ## a function that will `switch` based on the levels 1:10
  ## note that it is Vectorized (to avoid calling `sapply`
  switch_industry <- Vectorize(function(i) { switch(i, 1,1,2,3,1,1,4,6,6,5)})


  DatosMex[, gr_industry := switch_industry(cod_industria)]
```

I would not call this a `data.table`-specific solution.